# Global births for past 10k years?

Tags: data-request

Is there a resource or estimate for the annual number of global births for the past 10,000 years (or further)? Even if not annual, something with a reasonable enough frequency that I could do some sort of regression?

Answer (score 4):

This author (Scott Manning) reviews various sources for historical earth population
http://www.scottmanning.com/content/year-by-year-world-population-estimates/

At this link, he has an excel file showing various sources for estimating back to 10000 BC.
https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pbb0aoD3hdM-HgD-knTGXIA